# Open project made on OSX lion on a windows computer with QGIS

Tags: qgis, mac, windows, qgis-2.8

I made a project in my personal computer (mac OS Xlion) and now I would like to modify it on my work computer (windows 7), Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't tested this but considering [QGIS is cross-platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGIS), I would imagine you can copy over your shapefiles and project files over to Windows and load it without a problem.

Comment: If you have saved your project as a .qgs file, you should be able to open it in windows as well. Like @Joseph said QGIS is cross-platform

Comment: yes I saved it as a .qgs but it opens a window ``Handle bad layers`` and when i tried something he write me that there still 5(in this case) unhandled layers

Comment: .qgs file, not .prj file. The second is something completely different!

Answer (score 4):

You might get problems with the folder structure, if project file and datasources are not in the same folder, or you used absolute instead of relative folder names.

But you can look into the project file with any text editor and fix that.

---

If your datasources are all in one folder on the mac, save the project file into that same folder using **relative** paths. You can choose that under `Project -> Project Properties`, `General` tab.

Then copy all to the windows machine, and look if it works now.

If not, open a new project and add the same layers. Now you can compare the two project files, especially the part where the layers are loaded between the `<datasource>` tags. Change the Mac file to the same structure as the windows file, and it should work.

Comment: I think that is it! but how to change this?