# How to open none .qgs files in QGIS Wien?

Tags: qgis, export

I have tried tried to open my older qgis files made on a mac on my new PC. 
Wien(2.8) only seems to allow .qgs files so all my folders appears empty when I access them from QGIS on the PC.

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139734/open-project-made-on-osx-lion-on-a-windows-computer-with-qgis) might be helpful.

Comment: Unless the qgis project is extremely complicated, I would recommend just moving the data itself since the data is the same no matter what platform it's on.  You can export and then import any styles you might have after that to recreate the project.

Comment: QGIS saves the layers with relative paths into the project file. If the folder structure on the PC is different than on the MAC, you will not get the same content. It might help to put data and project file into the same folder, and to avoid non-ASCII or blanks in file names.

Comment: If I have a shapefile on a disk I thought that It would be possible to open it on an other computer?