# Moving project, settings & plugins from Mac to Windows PC?

Tags: qgis, qgs

I am a complete novice with QGIS.

I have completed my first project in QGIS 2.18.9 on a Mac. I need to transfer it to another Windows computer.

How can I best do this while retaining all my settings and plugins etc.?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @AFinch74! Perhaps this post might help: [Open project made on OSX lion on a windows computer with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139734/open-project-made-on-osx-lion-on-a-windows-computer-with-qgis). In terms of plugins, you could transfer them to your Windows account: `C:\Users\You\.qgis2\python\plugins`

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to keep settings of the project, or settings of QGIS itself?

To save your project with all its layers, groups and styles I recommend using [QConsolidate](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qconsolidate/) plugin - it will copy all of your files including *.qgs* itself to a single folder (don't forget to check ["Show also experimental plugins" checkbox](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/using_plugins.html) to see it).

As for moving plugins - please follow @Joseph 's recommendations above and [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/how-to-install-a-qgis-plugin-when-offline).